# What does list[float] mean?

Tags: list, buffer, cython

I accidentally happened to write something like `cdef list[float] l`

It turned out that this can be successfully compiled, but only as a local variable inside a function as with any other buffer variable. I looked at generated code, and it's more complicated than with just `cdef list l` - extra code also had to do something with buffer.

So, is this a Python list, but with buffer protocol? What advantages does it provide? What are the use cases?

Please point me to official documentation, if it is documented somewhere (I failed to find)

Comment: Without looking at the code, my suspicion is that this is triggering it to try to compile something using the old buffer syntax (the one that's been superseded by memoryview mostly). This isn't likely to actually work because `list` doesn't support the buffer protocol. I suspect Cython should be improved to reject this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now had a chance to look at the generated code.

On Cython 0.29.x this gets interpreted using the [old-style `np.ndarray` syntax](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html#more-generic-code) - it adds a type check that `l` is both a `list`, and is a type with the buffer protocol containing a 1D array of `float`. Such a check will *never* pass and thus the code is useless.

The old `np.ndarray` buffer code predates type annotations like `list[float]` by a long time so didn't anticipate that it'd develop an alternative meaning.

Cython 3 is a bit cleverer about handling subscripted types. It simply interprets the type and `list` as ignores the `float` part. Since Cython can't enforce the element type there's nothing useful it can do with it.

### Edit:

Some example Cython 3 code (since you claim in the comments that it's different)

For `list[float]`:

```
 /* "lf.pyx":6
 * def g(x):
 *     cdef list[float] y = x             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 *     z = y[0]
 */
  if (!(likely(PyList_CheckExact(__pyx_v_x))||((__pyx_v_x) == Py_None) || __Pyx_RaiseUnexpectedTypeError("list", __pyx_v_x))) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
  __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_v_x;
  __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_v_y = ((PyObject*)__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_t_1 = 0;

  /* "lf.pyx":7
 * def g(x):
 *     cdef list[float] y = x
 *     z = y[0]             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 */
  if (unlikely(__pyx_v_y == Py_None)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable");
    __PYX_ERR(0, 7, __pyx_L1_error)
  }
  __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_GetItemInt_List(__pyx_v_y, 0, long, 1, __Pyx_PyInt_From_long, 1, 0, 1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 7, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_v_z = __pyx_t_1;
  __pyx_t_1 = 0;
```

For `list`

```
/* "lf.pyx":2
 * def f(x):
 *     cdef list y = x             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 *     z = y[0]
 * 
 */
  if (!(likely(PyList_CheckExact(__pyx_v_x))||((__pyx_v_x) == Py_None) || __Pyx_RaiseUnexpectedTypeError("list", __pyx_v_x))) __PYX_ERR(0, 2, __pyx_L1_error)
  __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_v_x;
  __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_v_y = ((PyObject*)__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_t_1 = 0;

  /* "lf.pyx":3
 * def f(x):
 *     cdef list y = x
 *     z = y[0]             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 * 
 * def g(x):
 */
  if (unlikely(__pyx_v_y == Py_None)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable");
    __PYX_ERR(0, 3, __pyx_L1_error)
  }
  __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_GetItemInt_List(__pyx_v_y, 0, long, 1, __Pyx_PyInt_From_long, 1, 0, 1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 3, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_v_z = __pyx_t_1;
  __pyx_t_1 = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for research and hint about old-style np.ndarray can be written as object[float]. However as for Cython 3 it looks to me that float part does not get ignored, because generated code for `cdef list[float] l` and `cdef list l` look differently

Comment: Recent versions of Cython 3 generate exactly the same code. I've edited an example into the answer

Comment: I guess that is the reason, I use 3.0.0a11 that generates extra buffer related code (just checked once again)